# How do I create a translucid grid composition using a GreasePencil object with LineArt Modifier?

Tags: transparency, grease-pencil, lineart

I'm completely new to Grease Pencil tool, I followed some tutorials about freestyle and grease pencil object.

I'm using a Grease Pencil object with a *LineArt* modifier to create some grahics. I want to achieve the image on the left in one render (image was made combining two renders in Photoshop. One of the silhouette and other with the two plane grids).

I can't seem to find a way of setting up the *Lineart* modifier to show all the meshes edges and the part that is black (fill) to be translucid so it shows all edges that doesn't appear on the camera angle

[image: left: desired result / right: current result]

[image: LineArt Modifier Settings]

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably not the most efficient method, but it might help you in your situation.

Simply delete all the face of the models (Only faces and not the edges)
Go to Edit mode > A to select all > X to delete > Only Faces

This is what I got:
[image]

---

## Edit

Make sure you have selected `Loose` in the *Edge Types* drop down menu of your *Line Art Modifier* or else, no loose edges and vertices would show up in the line art modifier.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! I think it may work even tho it's a destructive method.

Comment: @Casiel Checoni This may be hard to believe but, this is quite possibly the most efficient method there is. If you want a non-destructive method, duplicate the mesh(es) before deleting the faces.